# Translation port causing Error 400: Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port

Tags: apache, https, http-status-code-400

A port translation is configured on a firewall with public address to redirect an https request from https://customdomain.fr:8443 to https://localIP-apache-server.

The translation works well and the index.php page is displayed correctly.

When i authenticate to the portal, the url is changed to http instead of https, and the following message appears:

Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

If i replace http by https, the page is correctly displayed.

I use a wamp server. In my httpd.conf there is 2 VirtualhHost, one for port 80, and one for port 443. Both port are listened.
I tried to enable a RewriteRule in httpd.conf in VirtualHost 443:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" "https://customdomain.fr:8443/$1" [L,R,NE]
```

But the error 400 still occurs. It seems that Apache send the Error before the request is read by the VirtualHost 443.

So I tried to set the following code before VirtualHost 443 in httpd.conf:

```
ErrorDocument 400  https://customdomain.fr:8443/aaa/bbb
```

I do not have Error 400, but the displayed page is 
https://customdomain.fr:8443/aaa/bbb/index.php and not another page by example https://customdomain.fr:8443/aaa/bbb/order.php

Do you know a way to display the requested page using ErrorDocument or another way to solve my issue please ?

Comment: Just don't redirect to http. Using HTTPS only for login was common practice 10 years ago, nowadays you should serve the complete page via HTTPS.

Comment: https is not only used for authentication, but for the entire site.

Comment: But you are writing `the url is changed to http instead of https`. As you are talking about the forwarding config and not an unexpected fallback to HTTP I assumed that this was done intentionally. Therefore your page is not served fully via HTTPS.

Comment: Yes your right: the browser changed https to http automatically, the change did not do manually, it is why the error 400 occurs. I am not an Apache expert, so I didn't yet find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
enable HSTS by adding the following code in httpd.conf:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552001; includeSubDomains;"
```

In this case, the browser send all requests via https adn not via http.
Issue solved.

Comment: I would call that a workaround, not a solution. The clean solution would be to adapt the web application running on the server and change all `http://` links to `https://`

Comment: It's not a solution to the question asked, since it requires a client to FIRST go to the https endpoint, but the client doesn't know that, otherwise it wouldn't hit the http endpoint in the first place.